# Integrating metamask with customer profile

Tags: metamask, dapps, nft, accounts

We are heading for "traditional" consumer markets for which Blockchain is mostly unknown. Therefore we are seeking for possibilities to keep the blockchain as "far"/unvisible for the consumers even tough we use blockchain- and NFT-techology openly because of the security advantages and wider scale of possibilities.

Is there safe method to integrate customer profile with metamask? In the way that when customer signs in, he automaticly signs in to the metamask connected to his account.

Customer should be able to buy ntf, hold it and list it on sale on our website. (metamask therefore that he can also sign it on sale on opensea if wanted)

Answer (score 0):

In it's current implementation, once a user "Connects" a site to MetaMask, they remain connected until they choose to manually disconnect themselves. Applications have no ability to disconnect a connected MetaMask wallet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use services like Magic.link, which will enable you to sign in users through a simple email link, and automatically get a user wallet generated. From there you can perform any web3 wallet function that you can do with for example metamask. This will allow your users to manage their assets, buy NFTs etc without any of the complexities of handling a wallet on their own.

In order to integrate Magic.link easily, you can use a service like Moralis, which will let you authenticate users using magic.link with just one line of code.

You can check a [demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLJ4YejmG2E), and then the docs for [how to set it up](https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/users/crypto-login/magic).

Full disclosure, I work at Moralis.

Comment: Thank you, I definetly have to check if there possibilities to implement it to our service.